# bing maps add more pushpins

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps

i want to add more pushpins in this map. i try to just copy this part:

```
longitude[1] = 41.799645     //second defined Location
latitude[1] = 20.913514
title[1] = "Kipper Market"
description[1] = "Kipper Gostivar"
```

but i don't see any other added pin! can someone please help.
*i know almost nothing about java script so please don't judge me if i didn't compose my question right. 
thanx!

```
        function GetMap() {
            var longitude = new Array();
            var latitude = new Array();
            var title = new Array();
            var description = new Array();


            longitude[0] = 42.0076215        //two defined locations
            latitude[0] = 20.9689308
            title[0] = "Kipper Market"
            description[0] = "Braka Miladinovi 178, 1200 Tetovë, Tetovo, Macedonia"

            longitude[1] = 41.799645     //second defined Location
            latitude[1] = 20.913514
            title[1] = "Kipper Market"
            description[1] = "Kipper Gostivar"

            var total = 0                //number of locations

            var pinInfoBox;  //the pop up info box
            var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
            var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
            var apiKey = "<api key>";

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {credentials: apiKey});

            // Create the info box for the pushpin
            pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
            infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);


            for (var i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
                //add pushpins
                var latLon = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(longitude[i], latitude[i]);
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(latLon);

                pin.Title = title[i];//usually title of the infobox
                pin.Description = description[i]; //information you want to display in the infobox
                pinLayer.push(pin); //add pushpin to pinLayer
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
            }

            map.entities.push(pinLayer);
            map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);
            map.setView({zoom: 10, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(41.9117244, 21.0254933)});


        }

        function displayInfobox(e) 
        {
            pinInfobox.setOptions({title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible:true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,25)});
            pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
        }

        function hideInfobox(e) 
        {
            pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
        }


    </script>

    <style>
            #map { position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 800px; border:none;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetMap()">
        <div id="some stuff" style="width=100%; height:80px">
            some text
        </div>
        <div id="map" style="width=100%; height:400px">
        </div>
        <div id="some more stuff" style="width=100%; height:80px">
            some more text
        </div>              
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The following example shows how to add multiple pushpins into Bing Maps:

```js
var pinInfobox;

function GetMap() {

    var pushpinInfos = [];
    pushpinInfos[0] = { 'lat': 42.0076215, 'lng': 20.9689308, 'title': 'Kipper Market', 'description': 'Braka Miladinovi 178, 1200 Tetovë, Tetovo, Macedonia' };
    pushpinInfos[1] = { 'lat': 41.799645, 'lng': 20.913514, 'title': 'Kipper Market', 'description': 'Kipper Gostivar' };

    var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
    var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
    var apiKey = "<api key>";

    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { credentials: apiKey });

    // Create the info box for the pushpin
    pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
    infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);

    var locs = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < pushpinInfos.length; i++) {
        locs[i] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(pushpinInfos[i].lat, pushpinInfos[i].lng);
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(locs[i]);
        pin.Title = pushpinInfos[i].title;
        pin.Description = pushpinInfos[i].description;
        pinLayer.push(pin); 
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
    }

    map.entities.push(pinLayer);
    map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

    var bestview = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(locs);
    map.setView({ center: bestview.center, zoom: 10 });
}

function displayInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({ title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible: true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25) });
    pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
}

function hideInfobox(e) {
    pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id="map" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 450px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thnx for the answer @Vadim but can u please tell me what do i have to add in my code above for adding another pin (along with an infobox of course). because ur code for some reason doesn't work in my site. my code works but i cant add more than those 2 pins. im using WP. so which part of the code do i have to duplicate to add other pins? thnx

Comment: In your code the hard coded number of pushpins are added, so you could simply replace ‘i < 3‘ with ‘i < latitude.length ‘

Comment: Yes man. this one worked. thanx a lot! unfortunately theres no upvoting option in the comments. thnx for ur help.